# User in my GSuite Domain can access Apps Script Code but not the deployed Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

**QUESTION:** Why can't my colleague access this Apps Script Web App I've deployed?

### Summary Details

- I'm in a corporate environment: this is a paid GSuite account.
- This is an Apps Script application deployed as a Web App and anyone can access it.
- The application works perfectly for me, but my colleague gets the error in the image below.
- The error appears for both `/dev` and `/exec` deployments and in an incognito window with no other sign ins except this domain.
- My colleague can access the script itself, but not the Web App deployments.
- The URL is not being rewritten: the exact same URL yields different results.

---

### What It Looks Like

*This is what my colleague sees when loading the app URL, `https://script.google.com/a/macros/<<MY DOMAIN>>/s/AKfycbxk8...UecT3qYXIG7Ycn/dev`*
[image: Image of the error: "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time"]

---

### DETAILS

Below is the only code in the app, along with an index.html and script.js.html that I include as part of the template. So far, so standard.

**code.gs**

```js
function includeScript(filename) {
  return `<script>${HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).getRawContent()}</script>`;
}

function doGet() {  
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('dist/index.html').evaluate();
}
```

**Project/Deployment Settings**

The script itself is shared to the organization, via the `Anyone in this group with this link can view` setting.

The app settings are all set to their default values.  No triggers.  The deployment settings are to "Execute as:" `User accessing the web app` and "Who has Access:" `Anyone within <DOMAIN>`.

**Can anyone tell what's wrong with this deployment? Why can't my colleagues access my web app tool?**

Comment: Check browser logs, check executions logs, add anything unusual to your post

Comment: Add a [mcve] ( the 'dist/index.html' file is missing, consider to include  the appscript.json file too). Also ask your colleague to open the `/exec` URL using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled. As them to sign-in only using the company domain account. P.S. there are already 24 with the same error message -> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22unable+to+open+the+file+at+this+time%22+%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+is%3Aquestion&searchOn=3

Comment: In `/dev` it's expected that other users won't be able to access it, since they would need edit access to the script. In `/exec` I cannot reproduce this, are you sure you are trying to access a deployment that has access to `Anyone within <DOMAIN>`? Consider providing a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Kos: Great suggestion, I took a look and didn't see anything unusual.
@Rubén: I had him try `/exec` to the same effect. I read many of those prior messages, but it was `appscript.json` file that was the culprit. See posted answer!
@lamblichus: Couldn't reproduce either, was trying to find out why it was wedged. See posted answer!

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

It turns out you can set permissions on deployments all you want (in this case they were correct), but the web app won't use them properly if `appscript.json` is set to something different.

---

**My Deployment Settings**

[image: Deployment settings were set to open sharing.]

---

**My Hidden `Appscript.json` File**

[image]